# How to use $timeFilter in grafana with sql ? It is showing undefined in generated sql

Tags: grafana, clickhouse

I am trying to use the $timeFilter variable in grafana with clickhouse as my database.
The query I am writing is this :

***select timestamp from pw.lte_avail_key where $timeFilter***

The Generated SQL by Grafana is this:

***select timestamp from pw.lte_avail_key where undefined >= toDateTime(1615514208)***

In some panels, the query being generated is this:

***select timestamp from pw.lte_avail_key where timestamp >= toDateTime(1615514208)***

Why is this random issue occuring? Please help.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the [doc](https://grafana.com/grafana/plugins/vertamedia-clickhouse-datasource/):

> $timeFilter - replaced with currently selected "Time Range". Requires
> Column:Date and Column:DateTime or Column:TimeStamp to be selected.

Make sure you define the *Column:Date* and *Column:DateTime*:

[image]